# ExtJS Catch event when query execution time exceeds the timeout

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have an ajax TreeStore with 5000 ms timeout and I want to catch the event when query execution time exceeds the timeout. How can I do it?

My TreeStore:

```
Ext.define('Portal.store.ObjectsTreeStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'Portal.model.ObjectsTreeModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'my/url.json',
        timeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function() {
            console.log('1');    
        },
        load: function() {
            console.log('2');    
        },
        exception: function() {
            console.log('3');    
        }
    }
});
```

With this code I only catch `beforeload` event when query execution time is exceeded and request canceled. When everything is ok I catch `beforeload` and `load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just attach your exception listener to the proxy instead of the store. See example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/psj

Comment: Thanks, in your example all works as I expect but I cant get it work in my code. Ill try to check my code more deeply.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax store proxy uses [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) in the background to send HTTP requests to the server. You could register [requestexception event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection-event-requestexception) handler on [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) singleton, something like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.on('requestexception', function() {
    console.log('HTTP error');
});
```

Just be careful because this event handler will be fired no matter who originated the request so it is system wide (global) and not specific to the component that initiated the request (`Portal.store.ObjectsTreeStore` in your case).